# Data Frame, Subset the user name and print the max and print the max value of each column in the subset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying this pandas coding problem but don't know how to do it. the code below is what I could do but it's showing error. can anybody help me and give me an explanation on how to do it? Thank You.

The `Cars` dataset has three columns giving the quality, machining angle, and machining speed of 18 cars.

Write a program that performs the following tasks:

1. Load the data `Cars.csv` into a data frame called `cars_df`.
2. Subset the first `userNum` rows of the data frame into a new data frame.
3. Find and print the maximum values of each column in the subset.

```
Ex: If the input is:
5
the output is:

Quality    5
Speed      4
Angle      3
dtype: int64
```

my code:

```
import pandas as pd


cars_df = pd.DataFrame("Cars.csv")# Import the CSV file Cars.csv

userNum = int(input())

# Subset the first userNum rows of the data frame
userNum = pd.iloc[:0,:]
userNum.max()
print(userNum)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    cars_df = pd.DataFrame("Cars.csv")# Import the CSV file Cars.csv
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 730, in __init__
    raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

I am a beginner in python and most of the time I am very clueless about the coding. I don't know how to do this code. your help and the explanation for this coding will be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure to point out in the question (and tags) that this is a pandas question, not just (base) Python.

Comment: Try changing `userNum = pd.iloc[:0,:]` to `cars_df.iloc[:userNum]`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after

```
cars_df = pd.DataFrame("Cars.csv") # Import the CSV file Cars.csv

user_num = int(input())

subset = cars_df.head(user_num)

print(subset.max())
```

Instead of the last line, you could call

```
print(subset.describe())
```

Which would give you a lot more stats than just `.max()`